# How to change FROM name with mailutils?

Tags: 20.04, mail

I have a script that sends email with some server info regularly. I use following command within a script

```
cat $msg |mail -r script1@my.domain.com -s "server event" myemail@adress.com
```

The problem with Ubuntu machines is they always put `"root <script1@my.domain.com>"` in FROM header, so when I receive email it just says from **root**.  
Since I have many different machines I would like to see email address.  Within *Fedora* works normally  with same command, and email has only email address as `From header`. 
I've tried to use  `-r Script1 <script@my.domain.com>` (gives an error) or `-u Script1 -r script@my.domain.com`  but result is the same. `mail` appends name "root" to From header so I only see as email from root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution when putting all in one line:

```
cat $msg |mail -a "From: Script1 <script1@my.domain.com>" -s "server event" myemail@adress.com
```

but if I use variable for `From:` field, it keeps giving me an error.

```
msg="Message to send"
EMTO="myemail@address.com"
EMFR='-a "From: Script1 <script1@my.domain.com>"'
cat $msg |mail $EMFR -s "server event" $EMTO

mail: Cannot parse address `<Script1@my.domain.com>"' (while expanding `<script1@my.domain.com>"'): Malformed email address
```

Closest I can get to working option is defining just email like following:

```
msg="Message to send"
EMTO="myemail@address.com"
EMFR="Script1 <script1@my.domain.com>"
cat $msg |mail -a "From: $EMFR" -s "server event" $EMTO
```

I would like to avoid modifying `mail` command, as I have a lot o them through out each script, whereas `email addresses` are defined only on top.  Any clues?